# Visual Studio 2010 installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-xp, installation

Is it possible to install `VS 2010` & `.NET 4.0` in `Windows XP` machine with `SP2`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Nope**. you need at least winxp with **Service pack 3**.

Comment: " Windows XP (x86) with Service Pack 3 - all editions except Starter Edition ". Is about 32bit version and not about 64bit version.

Answer (score 4):

[Visual Studio 2010 System Requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=06a32b1c-80e9-41df-ba0c-79d56cb823f7&displaylang=en#Requirements)

Answer (score 3):

It's not mentioned on the requirements page posted by LukeH, but if it's 64-bit XP, then yes.  I don't know if this is an official answer but I've been using it every day for the last few months.  There is only SP1 and SP2 for x64 XP.  The service packs for x86 and x64 aren't the same.

BTW, if you are using x64 XP then you should also install the Windows Automation API 3.0 for x64 Server 2003, here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981741.  There's no official version for x64 XP, but again, I've been using this for a few months with no problem.

(Before you tell me to upgrade, I'm forced to use XP at work.  I assume OP is too.  Pity us. :)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=12187#Requirements

System requirements

Supported Operating Systems: Windows 7, Windows Server 2003 R2 (32-Bit x86), Windows Server 2003 R2 x64 editions, Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2, Windows Vista Service Pack 2, Windows XP Service Pack 3

```
    Windows XP (x86) with Service Pack 3 - all editions except Starter Edition
    Windows Vista (x86 & x64) with Service Pack 2 - all editions except Starter Edition
    Windows 7 (x86 and x64)
    Windows Server 2003 (x86 & x64) with Service Pack 2 - all editions
        Users will need to install MSXML6 if not already present
    Windows Server 2003 R2 (x86 and x64) - all editions
    Windows Server 2008 (x86 and x64) with Service Pack 2 - all editions
    Windows Server 2008 R2 (x64) - all editions

Supported Architectures:
    32-Bit (x86)
    64-Bit (x64) (WOW)
Hardware Requirements:


    More information on how to choose the right hardware for Visual Studio 2010 can be found at http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/sysreqs
    Computer with a 1.6GHz or faster processor
    1024 MB RAM (1.5 GB if running in a virtual machine)
    3 GB of available hard-disk space
    5400 RPM hard drive
    DirectX 9 capable video card running at 1024 x 768 or higher-resolution display
    DVD-ROM Drive
```